# Swift MPSCNNConvolution -- weights all set to 1, shouldn't the output look just like the input?

Tags: swift, macos, neural-network, conv-neural-network, macos-big-sur

Trying to figure out how to use `MPSCNNConvolution`. I have a 4 x 3 image, and a 4 x 3 kernel. I'm setting all the weights to 1, and all the inputs to 1, and I sort of expected to get all 1's back. What I get instead is

```
12  9  6  3
 8  6  4  2
 4  3  2  1
```

The problem is that I don't know whether it's supposed to behave like this or not. I've been all over every shred of Apple doc I can find, every online article, every github repo, and I can't find anything that says what kind of output to expect when the layer is set up correctly.

The pattern holds for differently sized images. A 3 x 2 gives me

```
6 4 2
3 2 1
```

And a 2 x 2 gives me

```
4 2
2 1
```

I've pushed my "minimal" example to [github](https://github.com/SaganRitual/CnnLayer). It's not small. Xcode 12.4 no longer supports Float16, so there's utility code for floating between Float16 and Float32, plus all the convoluted setup for convolution, and yet more code for trying to un-headache un-safe pointers.

My specific questions: is this output "just the normal behavior" for `MPSCNNConvolution`? Is there a name for this function/algorithm, something I can look up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for `MPSCNNConvolution` is slightly confusing. To the uninitiated, it might seem that `MPSCNNConvolution` is a kind of container that holds convolution kernels. This is not the case. `MPSCNNConvolution` ***is itself a kernel***. Specifically, it weights and sums all the input values under the kernel window. Just a straight sum, no averaging or maxing. What you're seeing is the result of the kernel starting at (0, 0) and sliding way off the right edge, and eventually way off the bottom edge.

Set your kernel offset and your clip rectangle on the input image, and `MPSCNNConvolution` will work the same way as `MPSCNNPooling*` kernels and all the others